# Computing the product of orthonormal vectors and symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real, symmetric matrix. Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be any two distinct orthonormal vectors, i.e., $||v_1|| = ||v_2|| = 1$ and $v_1^\top v_2 = v_2^\top v_1 = 0$. I want to compute the following quantity:

$$\text{max} \, v_1^\top A v_2 v_2^\top A v_1$$

and identify vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ when the maximum value is achieved.

My claim is that the maximum value is 0 since this product is always 0 for any two orthonormal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. And therefore, the maximum value can be achieved when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are 2 distinct eigenvectors of $A$. Here is my reasoning for it.

First, $v_1^\top A v_2 = v_2^\top A v_1$ due to the symmetric property of $A$. And so, $\text{max} \, v_1^\top A v_2 v_2^\top A v_1 = \text{max} \, (v_1^\top A v_2)^2$. Since this is a scalar, the minimum value is 0. Partial differentiating w.r.t. $v_1$ and $v_2$, we get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v_1} (v_1^\top A v_2)^2 = 2 \, \cdot \, (v_1^\top A v_2) \, \cdot (A v_2)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v_2} (v_1^\top A v_2)^2 = 2 \, \cdot \, (v_1^\top A v_2) \, \cdot (v_1^\top A)$$

Let $v_1^*$ and $v_2^*$ be non-zero vectors that maximize $(v_1^\top A v_2)^2$ . The gradient of a function at it's maximum value must equal the zero vector. Therefore

$$2 \, \cdot \, ({v_1^*}^{\top} A v_2^*) \, \cdot (A v_2^*) = 0$$
$$2 \, \cdot \, ({v_1^*}^{\top} A v_2^*) \, \cdot ({v_1^*}^{\top} A) = 0$$

This implies, ${v_1^*}^{\top} A v_2^* = 0$. And therefore, $\text{max} \, (v_1^\top A v_2)^2 = ({v_1^*}^{\top} A v_2^*)^2 = 0$.

Specifically, is this argument/answer valid? Is there an alternative, easier method to show this true (or is this a standard result)?

Note: Separately, it is easy to verify that when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are eigenvectors, the value of the objective function is 0.

Comment: Over what set do you take the $\max{}$? Is it the set of pairs of orthonormal vectors or _all_ vectors?

Comment: Oh, right. I should have clarified that. Yes, over the set of all pairs of orthonormal vectors.

Comment: you say  
*My claim is that the maximum value is 0 since this product is always 0 for any two orthonormal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. And therefore, the maximum value can be achieved when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are 2 distinct eigenvectors of $A$.*    Consider $A =\mathbf e_1 \mathbf e_1^T =\begin{bmatrix} 1 &\mathbf {0}\\ \mathbf {0} &\mathbf {0}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf v_1 \propto \mathbf e_1 +\mathbf e_2$ and $\mathbf v_2 \propto \mathbf e_1 -\mathbf e_2$ (standard basis vectors $\mathbf e_k$).  I get $ \mathbf v_1^\top A \mathbf  v_2 \mathbf v_2^\top A \mathbf v_1 = \frac{1}{4}\gt 0$

Comment: I don't follow how you get $\frac{1}{4}$ in the above case. Could you please clarify?